Replacement for /usr/bin/logger?
I am looking for a replacement for good old logger which is adapted to the new macOS logging. It should which read from stdin.
Especially I want to set a kind of tag to more easily filter output later on in Console.app resp. log.

Are you looking to replace the apple log implementation entirely and go back to using a flat file?

Hi, no, on the contrary. I want to use the standard Apple log but feed it from the command line but want to add some extra meta information for filtering

Aah - might you edit in the command you want to use (even if it doesn't work) with specific examples of meta data, then list what the result should look like in console.app? Last I checked there were 28 event types, so covering everything without knowing your use case is a bit of guesswork.

I would start with blowhole to replace Apple's logs if you need a command line tool.

Thanks @bmike, I will look into this.
